# Email verification link to the users in self registration

Tags: email, community

Hello all,
              A small attention to all the Sales force delegates. I  have make an Web app with the community.

**My query is that  when the user self registered then the  verification link  send to  the user email Address.**

Through this link user can set his password and we  will satisfied  that the dummy users aborted while register into the community .  is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please be more specific with your questions.

Comment: @BradleyDelaune I want to  send an verification link when the user self  registered..Can you  expalin with this through an example.